# unir datos financieros de diferentes indices bursatiles

Tags: r, rstudio

No soy muy experto utilizando R y me gustaría trabajar con diferentes indices bursatiles (sus rendimientos diarios) para realizar un estudio de contagio de la volatilidad para un trabajo

Por ejemplo con el Ibex35, con el DAX-30 y con NIKKEI.

Lo que hago para cada uno de los indices es esto:

```
getSymbols("^IBEX",,from="1999-01-01", to = "2022-03-18")
IBEX1<-na.locf(IBEX, fromLast = TRUE) 
r1 = diff(log(IBEX3[,4]))*100
r1
```

Obtengo sus rendimientos y una vez tengo r1, r2 y r3 quiero unirlos. Lo que sucede es que cada uno de estos indices tiene missings, operan en dias distintos, etc..Eso hace que para un indice puede que un dia haya dato y para ese mismo día en otro indice no, generando algunos missings al unirlos .
Cabe decir que para unirlos he usado la funcion `cbind`

¿Se os ocurre qué puedo usar? O referencias donde trabajen esta tematica? Sinceramente no he encontrado mucho al respecto

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar la unión de los datos puedes buscar por opciones para realizar `merge` en R.

Hay opciones en R base y en varios paquetes como `data.table`, `dplyr`, e incluso en los paquetes `zoo` y `xts` que operan en objetos como los que estás usando.

### Para unir las series usando la función `merge` del paquete `xts`

Obteniendo los datos:

```
library(quantmod)
library(zoo)
library(xts)

getSymbols("IBEX", from = "1999-01-01", to = "2022-03-18")
getSymbols("DAX", from = "1999-01-01", to = "2022-03-18")

IBEX1 <- na.locf(IBEX, fromLast = TRUE)

DAX1 <- na.locf(DAX, fromLast = TRUE)
```

Procesando como lo has hecho anteriormente:

```
r1 = diff(log(IBEX1[,4]))*100

r2 = diff(log(DAX1[,4]))*100
```

Chequeando la dimensión de cada objeto:

```
> dim(r1)
[1] 406   1

> dim(r2)
[1] 1863    1
>
```

Usando la función del paquete `xts` para unir los datos manteniendo todas las líneas en cada tabla e incluyendo "NA" en caso que haya valores ausentes para el índice de fecha:

```
r1r2 = xts::merge.xts(r1, r2, join = "outer", fill = NA)
```

Chequeando el resultado:

```
> head(r1r2)
           IBEX.Close  DAX.Close
2014-10-23         NA         NA
2014-10-24         NA -0.2379026
2014-10-27         NA -0.6451932
2014-10-28         NA  1.9075334
2014-10-29         NA  0.6252463
2014-10-30         NA -1.0967639

> tail(r1r2)
           IBEX.Close  DAX.Close
2022-03-10   2.904127 -3.0395187
2022-03-11  -2.716216 -0.2638027
2022-03-14  -1.704049  2.5704562
2022-03-15   2.947846  0.7985683
2022-03-16   4.767111  4.6410481
2022-03-17  -1.963765 -0.1743037

> dim(r1r2)
[1] 1863    2
```

Puedes buscar información adicional sobre la función en R:

```
?merge.xts
```

### Usando paquete `zoo`

```
r1r2z = zoo::merge.zoo(r1, r2, fill = NA)
```

Para saber más sobre la función usa la ayuda en R:

```
?merge.zoo
```

### Usando paquete `data.table`

Si no deseas mantener la estructura del dato, puedes usar otro paquete para realizar la unión de las tablas. Con `data.table` podrías hacer lo siguiente, por ejemplo:

a. Transformar en `data.table` cada objeto

```
library(data.table)

dtr1 = as.data.table(r1$IBEX.Close)

dtr2 = as.data.table(r2$DAX.Close)
```

b. Unir las tablas por la columna 'index':

```
dtr12 = dtr1[dtr2, on = .(index) ]
```

Lo que genera la siguiente tabla:

```
> dtr12
           index IBEX.Close  DAX.Close
   1: 2014-10-23         NA         NA
   2: 2014-10-24         NA -0.2379026
   3: 2014-10-27         NA -0.6451932
   4: 2014-10-28         NA  1.9075334
   5: 2014-10-29         NA  0.6252463
  ---                                 
1859: 2022-03-11  -2.716216 -0.2638027
1860: 2022-03-14  -1.704049  2.5704562
1861: 2022-03-15   2.947846  0.7985683
1862: 2022-03-16   4.767111  4.6410481
1863: 2022-03-17  -1.963765 -0.1743037
```

Comment: Hola José, muchas gracias por responder a mi consulta y muchas gracias por los métodos ofrecidos, creo que me pueden ser de mucha ayuda. Gracias de corazón!

Comment: Hola Alex, me alegra que la respuesta haya sido útil. Mucha suerte con tus trabajos en R!